# Does flatMap functional signature (input -> output) proposes its doing any flattening?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, coding-style, code-cleanup

`flatMap` signature:

```
 /* applies a transformation of the monad "content" by composing
  * this monad with an operation resulting in another monad instance 
  * of the same type
  */
  def flatMap(f: A => M[B]): M[B]
```

is there anyway to understand by its signature (input to output) (except for the name `flat`) that its flattening the structure? or must I read its implementation to understand that? isn't good coding practice means I can understand by the signature of the function (input to output even without function name) exactly what it does? if so how does `flatMap` follows this basic programming practice? or does it **violates** it?

Comment: If you would just use `map` with a `f: A => M[B]` you would end up with a `M[M[B]]`. So with `flatMap` you're flattening

Comment: `flatMap` is equivalent to `join (map f m)` where `join` has type `M[M[A]] => M[A]` so it doesn't flatten the input structure but rather the mapped structure. This isn't immediately obvious from the type of `flatMap`.

Comment: What else could be flattened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It helps to understand that the type of the thing that `flatMap` is defined on is also `M` and would be something like `Traversable[A]` or a subclass such as a `List[A]`, or another Monad such as `Option` or `Future`. Therefore the left hand side of the function definition that `flatMap` requires (`f: A => M[B]`) hints to us that this function processes the individual items contained within the Monad, and produces M[B] for each one. The fact that it then returns `M[B]` rather than `M[M[B]]` is a hint that some flattening is taking place.

However I disagree that it should be possible to know exactly what a function does by its signature. For example:

```
Trait Number {
  def plus(that: Number): Number

  def minus(that: Number): Number
}
```

Without the function names and possible also some documentation, I don't think it is reasonable to expect that another person can know what `plus` and `minus` do.

Comment: To add to your point that a function's signature isn't everything (+1 btw): monads are defined by their **algebra** - that is, a set of operations (`flatMap`, `map`, `unit`, etc) and the operation's *laws* (e.g. `flatMap` is associative, and has a left identity and right identity). A method signature conveys a monad's operation, but not its laws.

Answer (score 3):

> Does flatMap functional signature (input -> output) proposes its doing any flattening?

Yes, it does.
In fact, `join` (or `flatten`), `map` and `unit` form a minimal set of primitive functions needed to implement a monad.
`flatMap` can be implemented in terms of these other functions.

```
//minimal set
def join[A](mma: M[M[A]]): M[A] = ???
def map[A](ma: M[A], f: A => B): M[B] = ???
def unit[A](a: A): M[A] = ???

def flatMap[A](ma: M[A], f: A => M[B]): M[B] = join(map(ma))
```

It should now be clear that `flatMap` *flattens* the structure of the mapped monad.

For comparison, here's another mimimal set of primitives, where `join`/`flatten` is implemented in terms of `flatMap`.

```
// minimal set
def unit[A](a: A): M[A] = ???
def flatMap[A](ma: M[A], f: A => M[B]): M[B] = ???

def map[A](ma: M[A], f: A => B): M[B] = flatMap(ma, a => unit(f(a)))
def join[A](mma: M[M[A]]): M[A] = flatMap(mma, ma => ma)
```